# How to add name and convert array values to JSON?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have an array, like this:

```
["1", "hello1@example.com", "user111", "something1"],
["2", "hello2@example.com", "user222", "something2"],
["3", "hello3@example.com", "user333", "something3"],
...
["N", "helloN@example.com", "userNNN", "somethingN"]
```

How can I turn it into JSON like this:

```
{ 
  "order" : "1" 
, "email": "hello1@example.com" 
, "username": "user111" 
, "note": "something1" 
},
{ 
  "order" : "2"
, "email": "hello2@example.com"
, "username": "user222" 
, "note": "something2"
},
{ 
  "order" : "3" 
, "email": "hello3@example.com" 
, "username": "user333" 
, "note": "something3" 
}, 

... 

{ 
  "order" : "N" 
, "email": "helloN@example.com" 
, "username": "userNNN" 
, "note": "somethingN" 
}
```

I'm self-study JavaScript, so I appreciate if you can suggest a similar case or document to learn more.

Thank you.

Comment: I'm thinking about run a for loop through the inside array, take out the first item "1" and put "order" : "1" back, take out the second item "hello1@example.com" and put back "email" : "hello1@example.com" and so on, until I have a right "name : value" paired array, then use json.stringify() that array.

Is it the good way to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this:

```
var arrayOfObjs = [];
for(var i in inputArray) {
    var data = inputArray[i];
    var obj = {
        order: data[0],
        email: data[1],
        username: data[2],
        note: data[3]
    };
    arrayOfObjs.push(obj);
}

console.log(arrayOfObjs);
```

You first loop through the array and since you know that the inner arrays are always of length 4 with [0 = order, 1 = email, 2 = username, 3 = note], you can safely create new objects and add them to a new array. You can also do this operation in array, which means that your input array gets updated with the new format (you basically do not create a new array):

```
inputArray[i] = obj; // replace line `arrayOfObjs.push(obj)` with this one
```

Comment: Thank you so much. The replace and update inputArray is easier for me to understand and use. So I accepted your answer. Have nice day!

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in many ways, e.g. using a classic for loop.

The way I currently favor is using Array.map:

```
array = [
    ["1", "hello1@example.com", "user111", "something1"],
    ["2", "hello2@example.com", "user222", "something2"],
    ["3", "hello3@example.com", "user333", "something3"],
    ...
    ["N", "helloN@example.com", "userNNN", "somethingN"]
];

var arr2 = array.map(function(el, i) {
    return {
        order: el[0],
        email: el[1],
        username: el[2],
        note: el[3]
    };
});
```

See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) for a reference. Lots and lots of goodies in there.

Answer (score 0):

In pure javaScript, I'd go for Chiesa's solution. If you'd like to use a libraray, here's a way to do it with underscore.js:

```
var new_array = _.map(array, function(entry) {
   return _.object(['order', 'email', 'username', 'note'], entry);
});

var json = JSON.stringify(new_array);
```

Comment: Yes, I agree that Chiesa's code is short, but I will use that way when I can understand JavaScript better. Thank you for your suggestion.